# How to dynamically create arrays within arrays with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
function pair(str) {

  // This function checks whether there
  // a certain letter in a string and checks
  // if it is followed or follows a specific
  // letter.

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    // If the letter isn't the letter "C"
    // before the "G", then it'll placed before it.

    if (str[i] == 'G' && str[i - 1] != 'C') {
      str = str.slice(0, i) + 'C' + str.slice(i);

    // The same goes for "A" and "T".
    } else if (str[i] == 'T' && str[i - 1] != 'A') {
      str = str.slice(0, i) + 'A' + str.slice(i);

    // And so on.
    } else if (str[i] == 'C' && str[i + 1] != 'G') {
      str = str.slice(0, i + 1) + 'G' + str.slice(i + 1);
    } else if (str[i] == 'A' && str[i + 1] != 'T') {
      str = str.slice(0, i + 1) + 'T' + str.slice(i + 1);
    }
  }

  str = str.split('');

  var temp = [];
  for (var j = 0; j <= str.length / 2; j++) {
    temp.push([]);
    for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
      temp[j].push(str.shift());
    }
  }
  return temp;

}

pair("TTGAG");
```

The string then becomes "ATATCGATCG". So far so goood. Each letter pair should be an array, and each array is an array item. The expected result is:

```
// > [ ['A', 'T'], ['A', 'T'], ['C', 'G'], ['A', 'T'], ['C', 'G'] ]
```

But instead I get this result:

```
// > [ [ 'A', 'T' ], [ 'A', 'T' ], [ 'C', 'G' ] ]
```

What is the mistake in the code? I tried several times to find the error but I haven't succeeded.

Comment: can the input string be "TAGC..." or is this simply a pair wise split.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem. The short answer is that the limit in the outer for loop needs to be set prior to the loop.

```
var limit = str.length / 2 -1;
for (var j = 0; j <= limit; j++) {
...
```

or

```
var limit = str.length / 2;
for (var j = 0; j < limit; j ++) {
...
```

The reason is that each shift operation in the inner loop, reduces the size of the str array by one. The `j <= str.length /2` expression is evaluated at the beginning of each loop - after the shift operation had taken place twice on the prior inner loop.

Initially `str.length / 2 == 5;`   `temp == [['A', 'T']]`

Then after two shift operations `str.length / 2 == 4;` `temp == [['A', 'T']['A','T']]`

After two more shift operations `str.length /2 == 3;` `temp == [['A','T']['A','T']['C','G']]`

The final time the outer for loop condition is evaluated str.length / 2 == 2, at that point j == 2 so the loop ends.

The MDN reference on for loops is helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: @brinquedo: happy to help

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly you are trying to take an input string like `"TTGAG"` and turn it into an array of `[A,T]` or `[C,G]`.

This is the approach I would take.

```
// renamed pair function for clarity
// assume genes == 'TTGAG'
function GeneStringToArray(genes){
    var geneSplit = genes.split(''); // [T,T,G,A,G]

    for(var i = 0; i < geneSplit.length; i += 1){
        geneSplit[i] = getGenePair(geneSplit[i]);      
    }

    return geneSplit; // out: [['A','T'],['A','T'],['C','G'],['A','T'],['C','G']]
}    


function getGenePair(gene) {
    // force lower case for ease of comparison
    char = char.toLowerCase();

    // Define our results
    var at = ['A', 'T'];
    var cg = ['C','G'];

    if(gene === 'a' || gene === 't'){
        return at;
    }

    if(gene === 'c' || gene === 'g'){
        return cg;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty confident that solves your problem in a clean, readable way.

Comment: Sure thing, did it end up working for you? If so would you mind marking it as the answer?